# remove country code after launch skype programmatically -Android

Tags: android, android-intent, skype

I want start a skype call from my app,
I use this code

```
Intent skype_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
skype_intent.setClassName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main");
skype_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 

skype_intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+99mynubber")); 
Context context = getApplicationContext();

context.startActivity(skype_intent);
```

this code work fine, but skype remove the + and add my countrycode calling +3999mynumber

how can I avoid this effect and call exactly the number I want?